# $span\{s+v\} = span\{s\} + span\{v\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

span{s+v} = span{s} + span{v}

Does the above statement always hold true?

In addition, what is the difference between span {s} $\cup$ {v} = span{s} + span{v} and the above statement?

Comment: Are $s$ and $v$ vectors or sets of vectors? If they are sets, how are you defining $s+v$? If they are vectors, how are you defining $s\cup v$?

Comment: Do you mean span {$s$}$\cup${$u$}=Span{$s$}+span{$v$}?

Comment: Hey i edited the question. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider the set {$(1,0)+(0,1)$} $=$ {$(1,1)$}.

The span of {$(1,1)$} is just a straight line through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{2}.$
While the span of {$(0,1)$,$(1,0)$} is all of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

On the other hand
span({$s$} $\cup$ {$v$}) $=$ span{$s$} + span{$v$} holds.